# zsh: command not found: flutter when creating new folder for MacOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am pretty new with Flutter and encountered this strange issue.
As per screenshot below, I managed to setup everything correctly and even managed to run `flutter doctor` command. However, when i changed my directory to a new folder and run `flutter doctor`, error message below will be displayed

> zsh: command not found: flutter

I have also set my path in my .zshrc file accordingly and that's why the flutter doctor command was successful everytime i run it. The only issue is when I change to a new directory. I have been searching for the solution for quite some time but seems that everyone advising to set the path in .zshrc file which i believe is not the case for my situation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the *absolute path* to the `PATH` variable. You have added the *relative path* from your *home directory* which is why it only works from there.

Add `$HOME/Development/flutter/bin` to the `PATH` variable.